# HTML code to be shown in messagebox WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my windows phone 8 application, I receive a html code in the response. The designer has asked to show this data on WP8 MessageBox. 
Is it possible or recommended to have a webbrowser in a windows phone 8 custom messagebox?
Also Is there any other approach for achieving the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the Windows Phone Toolkit's Custom Message Box and set its Content to a `WebBrowser` control with your custom HTML.

NuGet Windows Phone Toolkit or get it here : [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/).

Then the code is fairly simple

```C#
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // the web browser
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.Height = 300;

    // the HTML to show inside to browser
    string my_html = "<html><head></head><body>Hello from WP8</body></html>";

    // nagivate to the HTML
    wb.NavigateToString(my_html);

    // create our Message box
    CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
    {
        //Caption = "Allow this application to access and use your location?",
        //Message = "Sharing this information helps us provide and improve the location-based services offered for this phone. We won't use the information to identify or contact you.",
        Content = wb,
        LeftButtonContent = "allow",
        RightButtonContent = "cancel"
    };

    // show it
    messageBox.Show();

}
```

---

Code In Action

[image]

Comment: Yes even i had the same idea, but when I checked the design guidelines document for WP8 provided by Microsoft, In dialogbox it is mentioned : It may contain- checkbox, radio button, link control, puch button, Toggle button.

So, can i still use the webbrowser element in the messagebox??

Comment: @user1917864 in the toolkit:CustomMessageBox you can use whatever you want, you can even load in www.google.com if you feel the need to.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HTML or any formatting at all in the standard `MessageBox`. You need to create a `UserControl` that behaves like a message box where you can use the `HTMLTextBox` (or `HTMLViewer`) from https://msptoolkit.codeplex.com/. It is more suited for short HTML text than `WebBroser`